# URL Rewrite not working on .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have implemented my small website on a live server, however I want to use url-rewrite for some links to make it clean. I try this on my localhost server:

`http://localhost/cb/2/login.php` to `http://localhost/cb/2/login`

I manage to make it work on my localhost server by editing the `httpd.conf` of apache and enable url-rewrite. Here's the rule I added to apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/cb/2/login$ /cb/2/login.php   
</IfModule>
```

However, when I upload my files to a live server, obviously I do not have privilege to edit `httpd.conf` of that server, so I just put my rewrite rule on `.htaccess` file and here's the content of it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/login$ /login.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

But when I try to test it, `404 not found` is the response of server. I also try to implement in on my localhost server assuming I cannot edit the apache config and same error occurs, `Object not found!`

I have no idea what will I do next. I'm new to this url rewrite rule so any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After a lengthy discussion with the OP it seems there is a lot more going on behind the scenes.

The end result is no matter what is placed in the `.htaccess` file... it doesn't function.

OP was advised to contact the web host, but I will leave my original answer below for others on the site.

---

Remove the forward slashes from your rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cb/2/login$ cb/2/login.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

You changed your rewrite rule used on localhost when you put it on a live server. Assuming your directory structure is the same you should keep your rewrite rule the same (minus the forward slashes).

Remember in rewrite rules...

1. The text between `^` and `$` is what the visitor will input into the url bar, is what your link will be and is what the visitor will see in the url bar.
2. The next block is the location where the actual file exists.

**UPDATE**

If you want your visitor to go to `www.examplewebsite.com/login.php` and you want the url to look like `www.example.com/login`... your rewrite rule would be simply...

```
RewriteRule    ^login$    login.php    [L,QSA,NC]    # Handle log-in
```

Now... let's say that your `login.php` is inside another directory called `admin`...

```
RewriteRule    ^login$    admin/login.php    [L,QSA,NC]    # Handle log-in
```

These two lines mean...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If the url is not a "real" directory or the url is not a "real" file... then process the rule.

That's why using `RewriteRule    ^login$    index.php` causes your url to be rewritten as `www.examplesite.com/login.php` because the rewrite rule cannot be processed (index.php could not be found), BUT login.php is a "real" file.... so it goes to it.

Comment: what if I have an example domain `www.sampledomain.com` is this how I rewrite rule? `RewriteRule ^www.sampledomain.com/login$ www.sampledomain.com/login.php [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: No, you do not need the domain part. And you do not need the forward slashes. I will update my answer for further explanation

Comment: the code works now on my localhost, but I have no idea its not working on my hosting site. This is one of there features listed : `mod_rewrite enabled (apache 2.2); full dot files support (.htpasswd, .htaccess - posibility to set custom error pages, to block unwanted ips/sites, to turn on/off indexes etc. etc.);`

Comment: What is the **exact url** of where your login file is? For example `www.examplesite.com/login.php` or `www.examplesite.com/admin/login.php` ?

Comment: it's just on parent directory example: `www.examplesite.com/login.php` together with the `.htaccess` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91439/discussion-between-kuya-and-levince).

Comment: Hello, about the url rewrite, I manage to make it work on other hosting site. Thank you for your help. I will accept your answer since you explain url rewrite rule very well :)

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php
```

Comment: remove the begining slash: RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

Comment: now it works but when I type `/login` on browser, it rewrites to `/login.php`

Comment: You need to redirect all your requests to index.php and handle rewriting internally by means of includes, something like this: **if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) { include 'login.php'; exit;}** .... that way you can mask whatever url you want and parse the url parameters using php, another way is writing a more complex .htaccess to parse the parameters.